# how to traverse for input & textarea tag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get form elements values individually, to achieve this I have written the following code but It's not working.

```
$('#slider_btn_save').click(function(){
  console.log($('#frm_main_slider').find('input[name="*"]').val());
})
```

Comment: I want to get values of form input fields

Comment: When called on a collection of elements `val()` will only ever return the value of the one which occurs first in the DOM. You most likely need a loop here. It would help to see your HTML

Comment: `[name="*"]` it probably doesn't do what you think it does, it will look for elements with the value of the **name** attribute set to **\***. If you want to select all elements that have the name attribute, user just `[name]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this

```
let values = {};
$('#frm_main_slider').find('input[name="*"]').each(function() {
  values[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val()
})
console.log(values)
```